# c++: arithmetic operator overload

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have a class called `HealthPoints` that has `hp` and `max_hp` members. I want to overload the `+` operator so it will work like this:

```cpp
HealthPoints healthPoints1;
healthPoints1 -= 150; /* healthPoints1 now has 0 points out of 100 */
HealthPoints healthPoints2(150);
healthPoints2 -= 160; /* healthPoints2 now has 0 points out of 150 */
healthPoints2 = healthPoints1 + 160; /* healthPoints2 now has 100 points out of 100 */
```

I succeeded in making it work, but only in a specific order. If I put the number before the object, is there any way to make it recognize the number between the two of them and act accordingly? The way it works at the moment, I get that `healthPoints2` now has 160 points out of 160.

`HealthPoints` class:

```
class HealthPoints {
    public:
        static const int DEFAULT_MAXHP=100;
        static const int DEFAULT_HP=100;
        static const int MINIMUM_MAXHP=1;
        static const int MINIMUM_HP=0;
        explicit operator int() const;
        HealthPoints(int maxHP=HealthPoints::DEFAULT_MAXHP);
        ~HealthPoints() = default; // Destructor set to default
        HealthPoints(const HealthPoints&) = default; // Copy Constructor set to default
        HealthPoints& operator=(const HealthPoints&) = default; // Assignment operator set to default
        HealthPoints& operator+=(const HealthPoints& HP);
        HealthPoints& operator-=(const HealthPoints& HP);
        class InvalidArgument {};
    private:
        int m_maxHP;
        int m_HP;
        friend bool operator==(const HealthPoints& HP1, const HealthPoints& HP2);
        friend bool operator<(const HealthPoints& HP1, const HealthPoints& HP2);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const HealthPoints& HP);
};

HealthPoints::HealthPoints(int maxHP) {
    if(maxHP < HealthPoints::MINIMUM_MAXHP) {
        throw HealthPoints::InvalidArgument();
    }
    this->m_maxHP=maxHP;
    this->m_HP=m_maxHP;
}

HealthPoints operator+(const HealthPoints& HP1, const HealthPoints& HP2) {
    return HealthPoints(HP2)+=HP1;
}

HealthPoints operator-(const HealthPoints& HP1, const HealthPoints& HP2) {
    return HealthPoints(HP1)-=HP2;
}

HealthPoints& HealthPoints::operator+=(const HealthPoints& HP) {
    if(this->m_HP+HP.m_HP>this->m_maxHP) {
        this->m_HP=this->m_maxHP;
    } else {
        this->m_HP+=HP.m_HP;
    }
    return *this;
}

HealthPoints& HealthPoints::operator-=(const HealthPoints& HP) {
    if(this->m_HP-HP.m_HP>HealthPoints::MINIMUM_HP) {
        this->m_HP-=HP.m_HP;
    } else {
        this->m_HP=HealthPoints::MINIMUM_HP;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Make it non-member. Check Binary arithmetic operators section at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators.

Comment: @rturrado
it tried it, but now if i write `healthPoints2 = 160 + healthPoints1;` it doesn't work, it still returns that healthPoints2 now has 160 points out of 160.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this statement:

`healthPoints2 = healthPoints1 + 160;`

Your `+` operator is creating a new `HealthPoints` object that is a copy of `healthPoints1`, thus the object's `m_maxHP` is set to `100`. Then you are adding `160` to that object, increasing its `m_HP` but preserving its `m_maxHP`. Then you are assigning that object to `healthPoints2`, copying both `m_HP` and `m_maxHP` values. That is why the `m_maxHP` of `healthPoints2` changes from `150` to `100`.

In this statement:

`healthPoints2 = 160 + healthPoints1;`

Your `+` operator is creating a new `HealthPoints` object whose `m_maxHP` is set to `160`. Then you are adding `healthPoints1` to that object, increasing its `m_HP` but preserving its `m_maxHP`. Then you are assigning that object to `healthPoints2`, copying both `m_HP` and `m_maxHP` values. That is why the `m_maxHP` of `healthPoints2` changes from `150` to `160`.

If you want your `operator`s to update only the `m_HP` and not change the `m_maxHP`, you need to add overloads that accept `int` values instead of `HealthPoints` objects, eg:

```
HealthPoints& HealthPoints::operator+=(int value) {
    m_HP = std::min(m_HP + value, m_maxHP);
    return *this;
}

HealthPoints& HealthPoints::operator-=(int value) {
    m_HP = std::max(m_HP - value, HealthPoints::MINIMUM_HP);
    return *this;
}

HealthPoints operator+(const HealthPoints& HP, int value) {
    return HealthPoints(HP) += value;
}

HealthPoints operator+(int value, const HealthPoints& HP) {
    return HealthPoints(HP) += value;
}

HealthPoints operator-(const HealthPoints& HP, int value) {
    return HealthPoints(HP) -= value;
}

HealthPoints operator-(int value, const HealthPoints& HP) {
    return HealthPoints(HP) -= value;
}
```

And then, mark the `HealthPoints(int)` constructor as `explicit` to avoid unwanted implicit conversions when passing `int` values to parameters that are expecting `HealthPoints` objects.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure of the logic of your `HealthPoints` class, so double check my code below. My point, though, is to implement:

```cpp
    friend HealthPoints operator+(const HealthPoints& other, int value);
    friend HealthPoints operator+(int value, const HealthPoints& other);
```

You actually just need to implement the first one, and have the second one use it:

```cpp
HealthPoints operator+(const HealthPoints& hp, int value) {
    HealthPoints ret{hp};
    ret.m_HP = std::min(ret.m_maxHP, ret.m_HP + value);
    return ret;
}
HealthPoints operator+(int value, const HealthPoints& hp) {
    return hp + value;
}
```

You can see it here in action:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/fz9Y4cMWh)

```cpp
int main() {
    HealthPoints hp1{100};
    hp1 -= 50;
    std::cout << "hp1: " << hp1 << "\n";
    auto hp2{hp1 + 10};
    std::cout << "hp2: " << hp2 << "\n";
    auto hp3{10 + hp2};
    std::cout << "hp3: " << hp3 << "\n";
}

// Outputs:
//   hp1: (max_HP = 100, HP = 50)
//   hp2: (max_HP = 100, HP = 60)
//   hp3: (max_HP = 100, HP = 70)
```